# How to overite application.properties runtime using spring boot by creating end point in the rest application

Tags: java, spring-boot

There are few test cases which I want to execute with flag xyz_FLAG:true (in application.properties file)
By default this flag will be false for other test cases.

1.I have application.properties file in the one project where I have xyz_FLAG:false flag.
2.I want to create end point in the application and using that I want to override this flag as true.

3.So that I can run specific test cases with this flag.

1.I have an application which is dependent on another project called EY. In EY I have application.properties where I want set the flag as true by creating end point in the application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please check

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dynamicpropertysource
This might be what you are looking for.